# Moving into The Netherlands with my non-EU partner

Tags: visa, germany, netherlands, marriage, relocation

I am a Dutch/German and Brazilian citizen currently living in Brazil (been living here for 4 years now). Next year I will need to move back to The Netherlands, however, me and my Brazilian girlfriend would like to move together.

We are currently planing on marrying, but I am not sure what is our best bet due to our current circumstances. Would it be best to marry here in Brazil then move together to The Netherlands, or, marry in The Netherlands?

How would we legalize her in The Netherlands? Would marrying in Brazil help the legalisation process? Would I need to financially sponsor her independently if we marry or not?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken immigration is similar for the wife and partner in the NL. So I would say it doesn't matter but wait for someone with a real answer.